# Printing Problem - scanned Pdfs print black on black

Tags: pdf, printing, big-sur

tldr: I have scanned pdfs which look ok - like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xt2zsz8ygad9vz0/test%20scan.pdf?dl=0 - but they print like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ono1f39yv68sgql/output.pdf?dl=0

I have a grown archive of scanned pdfs (mostly through readiris).
Just recently I had to print out one and the result was unusable. (note: you can't see it in the scan - but if there are black letters they are actually slightly darker than background and a little readable.)

At first I thought it was the fault of a new HP printer, but no - on a OKI printer it is the same.
I also checked with several apps (PDF Expert, Acrobat Reader and Preview) - still same results.
From what I know it could even be a Big Sur problem.
Note - that in printing preview the page always displays correctly.
"Normal" pdfs print fine.

I can confirm that if I export the pages as an image and print this the results are with correct colors and white background.

**Update** - as suggested by @benwiggy - if the document is exported to Tiff and a Pdf created from this (both in Preview) the result is again printable.  (Unfortunately, this alone isn't a fix for me as I rely on the OCRd text.)

I did some research and found some discussions, but offered no answers:

- [hp support](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printing-Errors-or-Lights-Stuck-Print-Jobs/PDF-s-Print-Black-Background-on-Images/td-p/7176978)
- [apple discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250838599)

And there's a number of threads talking about transparency being printed black, but they appear specific to Apps I don't use - so not particularly useful.
Unfortunately none offered solutions to my problem.

I tried a number of things:

- reinstalling printer drivers/resetting printer system
- setting the background in preview to white
- resaving the pdf, flatten the pdf
  but they don't seem to work.

Anyone seen this and has an idea?

Is there a way to check a pdf for this error without printing it (going through black toner fast at the moment)?

**Update 2**
Not sure if this is related. But I was unable to open the Printer queue.
After investigating under `~/Library/Printers` there were Apps for my printer - but clicking on them gave an "Insufficient Permissions error".
Anyway - after playing around and enabling "open through Rosetta" they would open without error.

I was able to test on an Intel MacBook running Big Sur - it also prints the pdf black on black.

Comment: What happens if you export as a TIFF or PNG (which works), and then convert back to PDF? If you flatten the PDF, then surely there will be no transparency. Also: have you tried turning ColorSync OFF in the print menu options?

Comment: By the way, whatever that site is you're using to host the PDF files, it's spamming me to install Flash, and MacKeeper. I wouldn't trust it at all.

Comment: About the site. I was not sure how to share pdfs, so I took the first one suggested on reddit. Do you know a good place to put them?

Comment: About your suggestion - if I export to TIFF and recreate a pdf (both in Preview) it prints fine.

Comment: If I try to print it, CUPS throws a filter error, which is very weird. I seem to remember there was some issue in the past with MacOS and PDFs produced by some scanning software.

Comment: Can you tell how you get the CUPS output? I wonder there's also an error on my machine.

Comment: It shows in the print queue window, or you can check the logs in Console. But it simply refuses to print, which is curious.

Comment: Funny - I had to manually enable Rosetta to see the queue window. No errors appearing though.

Comment: On an M1? That might mean the printer drivers are running in emulation. Have you tried printing to Airprint? What model printers are involved?

Comment: Yes, a M1. I have an OfficeJet Pro 6960 and an Oki c3300. By now I have tried all variants of connection for the Officejet. The Oki only connects through IPP. Apart from this effect they appear to print as expected.